# Sort custom container (implemented as one integer)

Tags: c++, sorting, bit-manipulation

I have a class which holds small numbers inside bigger integer variable. It works fine and fast and looks like this:

```
template
class Container<IntegerT>
  static int bitsPerElement;
  IntegerT data; // [0000] [0000] [0000] [0000] up to 128bits(or maybe more)
  int size;
```

iterator as value_type return "reference" to container element:

```
Container::iterator
  DataRef operator*()

DataRef
  Container* parent;
  int position;
```

But i got a problem of unavailability of std::sort, because it have no clue how to actually swap elements of this container (direct swapping of DataRefs is obviously pointless).

Is there any magic way to make std::sort work with it (actually to force it use custom swap function)?

Or is there decent alternative to std::sort which can handle this situation? (storing DataRefs in array is not considered as a solution)

Which is the fastest way to sort this data structure?

```
#ifndef INTSTORAGE_H
#define INTSTORAGE_H

#include <algorithm>

template<class T> class IntStorage;

template<class T>
class DataRef
{
  public:
    DataRef(IntStorage<T>* parent, int position) : m_parent(parent), m_position(position) {}
    DataRef(DataRef&& o) = default;
    DataRef(const DataRef& o) = default;

    int value() const {return m_parent->value(m_position);}
    void setValue(int value) {m_parent->setValue(m_position, value);}

    DataRef& operator=(const DataRef& c)
    { setValue(c.value()); return *this; }
    DataRef& operator=(const DataRef&& c)
    { setValue(c.value()); return *this; }
    bool operator<(const DataRef& o) const
    { return value() <  o.value(); }

    IntStorage<T>* m_parent;
    int m_position;
};

template<class T>
class IntStorage
{
    template<typename> friend class IntStorage;
    template<typename> friend class DataRef;
  public:
    void append(int value)
    {
      data |= (static_cast<T>(value) << (s_bitsPerItem * size));
      ++size;
    }

    void setValue(int index, T value)
    {
      data = ((~(s_mask << (s_bitsPerItem * index))) & data)
             | (static_cast<T>(value) << (s_bitsPerItem * index));
    }
    T value(int i) const { return (data & s_mask << (i * s_bitsPerItem)) >> (i * s_bitsPerItem); }

    class iterator
    {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = int;
        using value_type = DataRef<T>;
        using pointer = DataRef<T>*;
        using reference = DataRef<T>&;

        iterator(IntStorage<T>* parent, int pos = 0) : ref(parent, pos) {}
        inline bool operator==(const iterator& o) const { return ref.m_parent == o.ref.m_parent && ref.m_position == o.ref.m_position;}
        inline bool operator!=(const iterator& o) const { return !operator==(o);}
        inline const DataRef<T>& operator*() const {  return ref;}
        inline DataRef<T>& operator*() { return ref; }
        inline iterator& operator++() { ++ref.m_position; return *this; }
        inline iterator& operator--() { --ref.m_position; return *this; }
        inline int operator-(const iterator& o) const {  return ref.m_position - o.ref.m_position; }
        inline iterator operator+(int diff) const {  return iterator(ref.m_parent, ref.m_position + diff); }
        inline iterator operator-(int diff) const {  return iterator(ref.m_parent, ref.m_position - diff); }
        inline bool operator<(const iterator& o) const {  return ref.m_position < o.ref.m_position; }
        DataRef<T> ref;
    };
    friend class iterator;

    iterator begin()  {return iterator(this, 0);}
    iterator end()    {return iterator(this, size);}
    iterator cbegin() {return iterator(this, 0);}
    iterator cend()   {return iterator(this, size);}

    static constexpr T s_mask = 0b111111;
    static constexpr int s_bitsPerItem = 6;
    int size = 0;
    T data = 0;
};

#endif // INTSTORAGE_H
```

Comment: wow insta -1 withing 30 seconds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You probably got downvoted for not researching that [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) comes in a 3 argument version.

Comment: I think not because of it because everyone know about it(including me) :) But it  cannot help here.

Comment: You asked about a custom sort.  The third argument to `std::sort` is the custom sorting function.  Why does it not help here?  It **would** help if you actually posted real code instead of a description.

Comment: May the downvoted is because you didn't  post a complete example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok ill post more code. i just thought that problem is clear :)

Comment: *direct swapping of DataRefs is obviously pointless* -- Then instead of swapping the data, create an index array and swap that according to the data.

Comment: why is swapping DataRefs "obviously pointless"? This is not how references should behave - calling `std::swap` on references should result in the actual swap in the container

Comment: This is what `std::vector<bool>` is doing, you may want to look into that

Comment: swapping of DataRef objects is pointless because this is just virtual refs which represents position in source container they are not part of container.

Comment: regarding std::vector<bool>: sorry but i cannot store 6 bit values as true or false :)

Comment: >> Then instead of swapping the data, create an index array and swap that according to the data.
This is to slow solution i mentioned it in post: (storing DataRefs in array is not considered as a solution)

Comment: @AustinPowers -- Why is this slow?  You are sorting an array of `int` if you're sorting indices.  You are **not** swapping the actual data.

Comment: @AustinPowers -- [A simple example of sorting "unswappable" data](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eeaa98b4a66d4d1)

Comment: @AustinPowers you still can use these references to extract and modify data in the contanier, right? they should work for swap too

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. it is not that slow as i thought. But still sorting of IntStorage<int64> with this method needs 160% of time needed to sort same data in vector<int>. But i need as much speed as possible. The main question is not how to achieve sorting of this data structure but how to do that with maximum speed. I think ill use sorting network for small sizes and this kind of "slow sorting" otherwise

Comment: @Ap31 they would work for swap. but i need to implement that swap by hand but std::sort always use std::swap

Comment: @AustinPowers no, you can totally overload `swap(DataRef<T>&, DataRef<T>&)` and `std::sort` will use it. However you have some inconsistencies in semantics: your `DataRef`s `operator=` assigns *values*, but the copy constructor copies the reference - I'd suggest to just declare it `delete`. Also your iterator `operator*` returns the reference to its state which is not the way it should work at all - it should not follow the iterator after it's been extracted from it:)

Comment: @Ap31 "you can totally overload swap(DataRef<T>&, DataRef<T>&) and std::sort will use it". Hmm... maybe im missing something? check this out: http://cpp.sh/85y5i

Comment: @AustinPowers yeah I'm sorry `std::sort` doesn't have to rely on `swap`, your type just has to be *MoveConstructible* and *MoveAssignable*. To be honest it's pretty much `vector<bool>` iterator debacle all over again. The `iterator::operator*` is not supposed to return a proxy type, but you can make it work if you fix the semantics

Comment: @AustinPowers -- *But still sorting of IntStorage<int64> with this method needs 160% of time needed to sort same data in vector<int>.* -- Are you running an optimized build, or an unoptimized "debug" build?  If it is not an optimized build, your findings are meaningless.  What are the compiler options you used to build your application?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie tested with -Ofast: got 177% of sort(vector) time

Comment: counting sort is O(N) and space is minimal for small BitsPerElement.